# Network.emulateNetworkConditions doesn't work in chrome 59 --headless

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, headless-browser

I'm trying to simulate regular 3G connection in `chrome --headless` (chrome version 59) by using [`chrome-remote-interface`](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface) with this [example](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface/wiki/Generate-timeline-data) as starting point

```
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');
const fs = require('fs');

CDP(async (client) => {
    try {
        const {Page, Tracing, Network} = client;

        Network.emulateNetworkConditions({
            offline: false,
            latency: 100,
            downloadThroughput: 750 * 1024 / 8,
            uploadThroughput: 250 * 1024 / 8
        });

        await Promise.all([Network.enable(), Page.enable()]);

        const { result } = await Network.canEmulateNetworkConditions();
        console.log(result); // always false

        // trace a page load
        const events = [];
        Tracing.dataCollected(({value}) => {
            events.push(...value);
        });
        await Tracing.start();
        await Page.navigate({url: 'https://github.com'});
        await Page.loadEventFired();
        await Tracing.end();
        await Tracing.tracingComplete();
        // save the tracing data
        fs.writeFileSync('./timeline.json', JSON.stringify(events));
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
}).on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

But [`Network.emulateNetworkConditions`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-emulateNetworkConditions) seems to not be working. To prove that [`Network.canEmulateNetworkConditions()`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-emulateNetworkConditions) always return `false`. Without `--headless` flag `Network.canEmulateNetworkConditions()` returns `true`.

`chrome-canary --headless` (version 61) gives the same results.

Is my example contains error or chrome 59 is currently lack of this feature?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Check https://crbug.com for an existing report or submit a new one.

Comment: @wOxxOm It could be lack of `emulateNetworkConditions` feature in `--headless` https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=728451&q=emulateNetworkConditions&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a missing [feature](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=728451&q=emulateNetworkConditions&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) in headless Chrome below version 64. Currently `Network.emulateNetworkConditions` works fine in Chromium and Chrome Canary (64) headless mode.

Comment: it doesnt work in undetected chromedriver with chrome 110